# Read a text file with Automator.app line by line

Tags: shell, applescript, automator

I'm a novice at coding so please be patient with me.

I've created a Workflow with Automator (OSX) which works fine. The only issue I have is that I want it to run on a number of inputs (that is as a batch). I've inserted the Loop action but the problem I'm having is about changing the initial input each time.

I would like to use an applescript to automate the insertion of the initial input each time.

I have a TXT file with URLs. With an apple script, I'd like to copy a URL (or a line of text) to clipboard.
In the next iteration I'd like to copy the next URL (or line of text).

Can anyone help?

Thank you!!

Comment: So, the whole autmator should do only do the next? 1.) get a next line from a file (1st at start), 2.) copy the line to clipbard, 3.) start again? (looping manually(keypress), or automatically by count?)

Comment: @jm666 The Automator would do: 
1. get next line from a file (1st at start)
2. copy the line to clipbard
3. Do all the remaining task in the workflow (This has been completed by me, no issue here)
4. Loop (Automatically by count, also completed by me, no issue here)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create one looping workflow (called as *LinesToClipboard.workflow*) what will

- get a line from an text file (not rtf, or doc)
- copy the line to clipboard
- run your current workflow
- loop again for the next line

The workflow:

- Create new automator workflow
- create a variable

  - at the bottom find the icon "Show or hide the workflow variables list" and show the workflow wariables (empty)
  - right click and "New variable..."
  - name the variable as "LineNumber"
- add actions:

  - `Get Value of Variable` (LineNumber)
  - `Run Shell Script`
  - shell: `/bin/bash`
  - **important**: change the `Pass input` to `as arguments`
  - add the following content (copy exactly, with all quotes and such):
  - in the content of script, change the `/etc/passwd` to the full path of your filename, like `/Users/myname/Documents/myfile.txt`
  - at the end of this action the clipboard will contain one line from the file

```
linenum=${1:-0}
filename="/etc/passwd" # full path of your text-filename
let linenum++
sed -n "${linenum}p" < "$filename" | pbcopy
echo $linenum
```

- `Set Value of Variable` (LineNumber)
- `Run Workflow` - add your current workflow (or the "ShowClipboard.workflow" - see bellow)

  - the `Wait for workflow to finish` should be checked
  - **important** The Output menu should be: "Return action input"
- `Loop`

  - add your count...
- `Run Shell Script` (Ignore this action's input), content one line: `echo 0` (This will reset the variable LineNumber to zero, when the loop ends)
- `Set Value of Variable` (LineNumber)

For testing, you can create another workflow, called *ShowClipboard.workflow*, with an content:

- `Get Contents of Cliboard`
- `Set Value of Variable` (clipval)
- `Ask for confirmation` (and drag the `(clipval)` to the Message field)

Run the first workflow.

Screenshots (for sure) :)

[image]

The second workflow (for testing)

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! Absolutely legendary, mate! Thanks, a day of youtubing and googling didn't help like you did!

Comment: @HarisAhmed Enjoy ;), Glad to help. ;)

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AppleScript to get the URLs but can directly extract them with Automator by using a shell task. After using the task that's getting contents of a folder (this is a Finder task in Automator), add a shell task as the next task. Make sure you select that the input is send as arguments instead of sending it to stdin. When you have done that you only need something like one of the following shell scripts.

```
cat $@ | egrep -io '\S?(http|https|ftp|afp|smb|mailto|webcal):\S+''
```

It first read all the files using cat. The `$@` is a shell variable that contains the arguments collected by the previous task: A list of paths to all files of batch folder. We pipe them to egrep will which will only output the URL filtered by their schemes. If you want to support any scheme (official and unofficial schemes):

```
cat $@ | egrep -io '\S?[A-Z][A-Z0-9+-.]+:\S+'
```

Comment: I used the shell scrip you gave me and it works wonderfully..
' cat $@ | egrep -io '\S?(http):\S+' '
However because all the URLs are now being processed together Automator crashes further down the workflow about 25% of the time.. I've only tested it with upto 4 URLs right now (but I'm expecting it would fail more often with more URL that are inserted). Ideally I'd want it to work with around 75-100 URLs.. This is why I wanted one URL to run through the whole process before starting with the next one.

Comment: I think it will crash because it will return an error when an file doesn't contain an URL. You can add " || true" at the end of the command. The || is an or, that means that when grep fails it will return empty by executing the true command.

Comment: How to just copy all URL to clipboard or to a new empty txt file?