# Apple Automator to view a list of URLs from a text file

Tags: automator

I run into scenarios where I want to compile a list of URLs in a text file. Then I want to use Apple Automator to view each one of those URLs in a browser.  My MAC is OSX 10.9.4, Automator V2.4. I can use

Get Specified URLs > Display Web Pages

but I have to cut and paste the URLs into Get Specified URLs. I want to read the URLs from a text file. I saw some posts that say to use "Get Specified Finder Items" >  "Combine Text Files" > "Filter Paragraphs" but this does not work either. The flow I am trying is

Get Specified Finder Items > Combine Text Files > Filter Paragraphs > Get Specified URLs > Display Web Pages

When I run this work flow I see Filter Paragraphs outputs the list of URLs but with parens around them

```
(
URL 1
URL 2
URL3
)
```

I see the output of Get Specified URLs is empty which causes the error "The action Display Webpages was not supplied the required data".

Comment: you want open all URLs from the file at once, or one by one? If one-by-one what should be the signal to open the url on the next line?

Comment: I would like to open up the URLs one-by-one. I do not know how to pass a URL one-by-one to the Display Web Page section then loop back and do the next URL

Comment: I have made a bit of progress with this. The following workflow will display all URLs in the text file in a separate browser tab, but all at the same time. 

Get Specified Finder Items > Combine Text Files > Extract URLs from Text > Get Specified URLs > Display Web Pages

It kills my browser when I have 50+ URLs in the input text file. I would really like it to open 1 URL, wait for me to kill that tab or something similar, then display the next URL.

Joe

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24886149/632407 similar problem: read a file line-by-line. you will need probably two workflows, one with loop action.