# Navigate to URLs in a text file one by one

Tags: shell, applescript, automator

I need to open a text file filled with URLs one by one, then perform actions based on each webpage before moving onto the next URL.

The question [Read a text file with Automator.app line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853112/read-a-text-file-with-automator-app-line-by-line) helps greatly, but the check doesn't work - and the first alert window shows all the URLs while subsequent alerts don't show anything. I'm guess the error has something to do with this section:

```
linenum=${1:-0}
filename="/etc/passwd" # full path of your text-filename
let linenum++
sed -n "${linenum}p" < "$filename" | pbcopy
echo $linenum
```

Additionally I'd like the copied URL gets pasted into Safari's address bar and navigate there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you text file is made of one URL per line (= per paragraph) and it is a 'txt' file. Then script bellow all help you :

```
set F to choose file "select your text file"
set myURLs to paragraphs of (read F as text)
repeat with aURL in myURLs
   open location aURL -- open in your default browser (ie Safari)
   -- do what ever you need to do, the URL is open
end repeat
```

This script also assumes that all your lines in your text file are valid URLs.